# Codelink package not installing

Tags: r, package

I try to install `codelink` package by

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("codelink")
```

once its done then by trying `library(codelink)` to use it, it give an error on `R version 3.1.3 RC (2015-03-06 r67947)`

`Error in library(codelink) : there is no package called ‘codelink’` Don't know what is going wrong

**Updated:** Some warning messages

```
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘XML’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘annotate’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
  installation of package ‘codelink’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `codelink` need dependency package `libxml2-dev` that was missing in my linux version. So if this is the case then, we need to run `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev` from command line to install the dependency. Once this is done , we can install the `codelink` package, which installs smoothly.